# UITableView inside UIScrollView, scroll not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to implement the following hierarchy

```
-- UISCrollView
  -- ContainerView
    -- UITableView
```

[image: Initial stage]

Initially the **`UITableView scroll`** is disabled. When the `UICollectionView` reaches a particular `contentOffset` of the `UIScrollView`, I implement this :

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= 140)
    {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 140) animated:NO];
    }
}
```

[image: After Scrolling]

All this works as intended, but now the UIScrollView is eating the scroll of the `UITableView`. The **scroll** of `UITableView` is erratic now and doesn't scroll properly. The scroll of `UITableView` happens only after 7-8 attempts and then it stops again.

What might be the reason of this behaviour? I tried setting `myScrollView.scrollEnabled = NO` inside `scrollViewDidScroll` and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can delay the main scroll view's touch response, then the sub tableview (scrollview) can be scrolled correctly:

```
myScrollView.panGestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
```